# SPARQL: query optimisation for subquery / subset

Tags: sparql, rdf, query-performance

i have been looking around a bit on stackoverflow as well on various other resources, but i'm struggling to get a specific query to work.

i have a graph with many parent /child relationships (1 milj nodes); and i would like to find specific nodes and then trace back to the root node.

[full graph size overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baE4W.png)

when i execute the subquery, to get the scope of nodes i want; i get sub-second results

```
select distinct ?af_node 
            # ?word_value
      where {

        {
            select  ?af_node ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "CompanySizeTurnoverSegmentation";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "NumberOfEmployees";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "CompanySizeSegmentation";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "Turnover";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "CompanySizeTurnoverSegmentation";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "AnnualAccountsFlag";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      }
```

[resultset 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb2Bg.png)

now, when i just use one node and follow it back to the root node, i still get sub-second results. in the result it is a short path, but there are others with more than 10 levels..

```
 select *
 where {

 ?af_node <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#ArteFact>;
         <cd:identifier>    "efac028c-ae79-4837-bb2a-01f8a12c5924";
        <cd:has_root>+ ?af_node_root
.
}
```

[result set 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppnT1.png)

however, if i try to combine both, the query takes ages, cpu and memory go through the roof; i guess there is some kind of Cartesian product going on.

```
select *
where {


  ?af_node <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#ArteFact>;
           <cd:identifier>  "450285fa-9390-41d7-ad51-006624c43db2"
  .
  filter exists {      
     select distinct ?af_node 
            # ?word_value
      where {

        {
            select  ?af_node ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "CompanySizeTurnoverSegmentation";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "NumberOfEmployees";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "CompanySizeSegmentation";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "Turnover";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "CompanySizeTurnoverSegmentation";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      union
        {
            select  ?af_node  ?word_value
            where {

              ?word <cd:is_a>   <http://site.eu/entity-type#Word>;
                    <cd:value> "AnnualAccountsFlag";
                    <cd:value> ?word_value;
                    <cd:is_related_to> ?af_sentence
              .
              ?af_sentence <cd:is_a> <http://site.eu/entity-type#SentenceWord>;
                           <cd:belongs_to> ?af_node
            }
        }
      }
  }
  .    
  ?af_node <cd:has_root>+ ?af_node_root
  .
}
```

[combined result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpYUK.png)

any idea what i'm missing here?

Thx!

H

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. 2. SPARQL is not a graph traversal language. 3. Which triplestore are you using?

Comment: 4. Perhaps you could use `VALUES` instead of `UNION` for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Four very good points from @StanislavKralin. Basically the same I'd also suggest. Starting with `VALUES` would make it much more readable indeed. Then what's the number of results returned by both queries separately? I don't see that much room for optimization once you use a FILTER the first part is always executed first, did your try a sub-query? Or can you share the dataset maybe?

Comment: It seems you are using Blazegraph. Try [query hints](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints). Rewrite your query using `VALUES` (and probably you need regular triple patterns instead of `FILTER EXISTS`). Add `hint:Prior runFirst true` after `?af_node <cd:identifier>  "450285fa-9390-41d7-ad51-006624c43db2"` and possibly also `hint:Prior hint:gearing "forward"` after `?af_node <cd:has_root>+ ?af_node_root`. You could also сheck the "Explain" flag in the "Advanced features" section.

Comment: Hi Stanislav, correct, i'm indeed using blazegraph; i have loaded the data via RDF/xml that's why there are the "<>" on the predicates... the `hint:Prior hint:gearing "forward"` seems to be causing java stack trace drump   `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bigdata.rdf.sparql.ast.hints.QueryHintException: scope=Prior, name=gearing, value=forward, op=PropertyPathNode` (not sure if i can past the full trace here...) .

Comment: thx a lot for the link to the MCVE, as mentioned in the first post, there are 1mlj nodes loaded, so i can't just share it. i'll see if i can scrub a small set.

Comment: java stacktrace : [here](https://paste2.org/ZW9kyWd7)  --  explain plan : [here](https://paste2.org/khhNCBx9)

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/krGaaGMc Are results correct? Is this query faster?

Comment: @StanislavKralin the query sure runs fast! i have the results now in 348ms. however, if i understand the query correctly, you filter all nodes which have a match to an exact literal value as defined by the value `VALUES ?value { }` construct.

Comment: ..however, the reason why i was using the complex `filter exists { {} union {} } ` construct is because i want to be able to use a pattern (subgraph) result as subquery. that pattern might be more exhaustive then just fetching nodes that correspond to a specific value matching; unless there is a way to put that pattern as subgraph in the `VALUES ?value { }` construct... if i understand the SPARQL doc correctly, i believe that is not the case

Comment: OK, rewrite your query, but paste `hint:Prior hint:runFirst true` after the most selective triple pattern. You could also try to insert this hint somewhere in your query: `hint:Query hint:filterExists "SubQueryLimitOne"`.